# How to use CyanogenMod-specific API properly

Tags: android, google-play, cyanogenmod

I am interested in the [ProfileManager](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/jellybean/core/java/android/app/ProfileManager.java) api, but I am to ask some more generic question.

1. How to include the class for cyanogen mod?
   Is there any SDK/library package, or shall I download the whole `android_frameworks_base` project?
2. How to configure eclipse to use this library?
   Should I check  `android_frameworks_base` as a library? Or do I have to copy the interface classes over?
3. Is it possible to limit this app to cyanogenmod on google play?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think that you should do this in the same way as [here](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/using-component.html) ... of course instead Build.VERSION you should use other info to get know if you're running your code on cyanogenmod or not ... then you could use java reflections to run cyanogenmod-specific API

Comment: @Selvin, your link describe how to make to compatible with other version. I just don't care about them (at least for now)

Comment: @SDIZ I also am interested in CM specific Profile APIs. Did you have any luck figuring out how to target CyanogenMod platform without having to build it from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps in the page below. Althought it is for android internal APIs, it is just the same for any CM APIs, so it just works. You might need to restart your IDE after the steps before the APIs are recognised, at least for me to use IntelliJ.

https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-2-hacking-around/

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly late to the conversation here, but as insight for anyone looking further -- CM has spun up a Platform SDK which makes things like the Profile API accessible via a statically linked sdk jar.

Details on the CM Platform SDK can be found here:
https://github.com/Cyanogenmod/cm_platform_sdk/wiki

With prebuilt jars available here (under current and future):
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_prebuilts_cmsdk